# about always on database replication

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

I added database in sql server always on structure , and database still restoring in secondary replica.

How can I find out percentage of replication ? Is there any query etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_hadr_automatic_seeding
```

If you have start the replica with automatic seeding

Comment: Hello , Thanks for reply but when I run the command just id information is coming no any progress information